# /home /opt /tmp /usr /var on a single partition of another hard drive Debian 8

Tags: linux, partition, mount, diskmanagement, debian-jessie

I have a production server for which I would like to move the /home, /opt, /tmp, /user, /var to the ~300GB partition specially created for this purpose.

No straightforward explanation found on how to do this, except that I can put every folder specified above on a separate partition, but I don't want to do that. Reasons:

1. I don't know how much space these folders might use in the end, so one drive with all of it will do nicely.
2. I see it much simpler for me. I don't want to have tons of partitions on the same drive.
3. I will install a server app, that will do much I/O and a MySQL server, and I don't want it to slow down the system hard drive or interfere with it.
4. [Intelligent partitioning](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch3.en.html)

Is there any way to achieve what I want, so all would work as if the folders are on the same hard drive?

P.S. These are the most rellevant links I've found so far:

[Link1_LinuxAndUnix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131311/moving-var-home-to-separate-partition)

[Link2_UbuntuDocumentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

[Link3_LinuxNewbieAdministrator](http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie4_2_6.htm)

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

All mounted!

UUID=rootUUID / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=swapUUID none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
UUID=otherDriveUUID /mnt/sdb2 ext4 defaults 0 1
/mnt/sdb2/tmp /tmp none defaults,bind 0 2
/mnt/sdb2/local /usr/local none defaults,bind 0 2
/mnt/sdb2/home /home none defaults,bind 0 2
/mnt/sdb2/opt /opt none defaults,bind 0 2
/mnt/sdb2/var /var none defaults,bind 0 2

Comment: Edited. Please review the on hold state and off-topic.

Comment: If you think it is expensive to replace an unreliable hard drive, then you probably don't know how much it can cost to keep using an unreliable hard drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is bind mounts. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html for details.

Here is a step by step guide to moving /home, /opt, /tmp, /usr, and /var to a single separate partition.

### Disclaimer

I am not responsible for any damage or loss of data caused by following this guide. As always, **ensure all important data is backed up before proceeding**.

### Step 1

Boot from your favourite live CD. Example: https://www.debian.org/CD/live/

Switch to root shell. This can often be done with `sudo su -`

### Step 2

Mount your primary and secondary partitions. We'll assume that they are `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` for the purpose of this guide.

```
mkdir /mnt/sd{a,b}1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

### Step 3

Move existing folders/data from primary to secondary partition. This may take a few minutes depending on the size of the folders and speed of your drives.

```
mv /mnt/sda1/{home,opt,tmp,usr,var} /mnt/sdb1/
```

### Step 4

Create empty folders on the primary partition to give us mount points.

```
mkdir /mnt/sda1/{home,opt,tmp,usr,var} /mnt/sda1/mnt/sdb1
```

### Step 6

Edit your fstab to automatically mount the secondary partition and bind mount the appropriate folders. This step is largely subjective to your current configuration and may not work as a direct copy/paste.

Edit `/mnt/sda1/etc/fstab` with your favourite editor.

You can find detailed information on the fstab at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html

First we need to mount the secondary partition before we can bind mount to it. This partition may already be in your fstab. If so, edit/remove the configuration accordingly. Here, we'll assume it's an ext4 partition with default options.

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1 ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Next, configure the bind mounts.

```
/mnt/sdb1/home /home none defaults,bind 0 0
/mnt/sdb1/opt /opt none defaults,bind 0 0
/mnt/sdb1/tmp /tmp none defaults,bind 0 0
/mnt/sdb1/usr /usr none defaults,bind 0 0
/mnt/sdb1/var /var none defaults,bind 0 0
```

Save your changes to the fstab.

### Step 7

Reboot

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I will try all steps, and if these will work, I will accept the answer. Also, very nice done and pretty explicit!

Comment: What I get is: mounting /mnt/sdb2/usr on /root/usr failed: No such file or directory, though I created the empty folder under root, and the other one contains all the data I moved. Also, fstab contains: /dev/sdb2 /mnt/sdb2 ext4 defaults 0 2 and /mnt/sdb2/usr /usr none defaults,bind 0 0 (Also with all other folders). What could be the problem?

Comment: As you are mounting in `/root`, I assume you are sand boxing the mounts first. Have you run `mount -a` (mounts all entries in `/etc/fstab`) or rebooted after updating your fstab?

Comment: I modified everything using debian live CD as you suggested. Rebooted. The message appears just after reboot, with some failed messages after it. Did not run any mount -a

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to mount in `/root`? Does `/root` exist anywhere in your fstab?

Comment: I did not understand the question. My fstab looks like this: UUID=rootuuid / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 uuid=swapuuid none swap sw 0 0 /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0 /dev/sdb2 /mnt/sdb2 ext4 defaults 0 2 /mnt/sdb2/usr /usr none defaults,bind 0 0 and all other folder mountings

Comment: I suppose there is something to be done with initrd, because even if I change /dev/sdb2 with UUID, I get the same error. But I know nothing about initrd...